# better way to record desktop via ffmpeg

Tags: c#, image, video, ffmpeg

in my form there's a timer that capture the screen as jpeg every 85 ms, it captures until the user shutdown the windows or electricity cut off so the last frame(image) may get corrupt which is okay for me, now when the user log in the form run on the start up now on the on load event it ask if there images in temp folder if yes it open `ffmpeg` to convert all images into one video but that seems to take a lot of time i have +300000 image and that because it capture the screen for at least a 10 hour every day but that will take a lot of time to convert them, i wonder if there any other way to directly record at a video and when electricity cut off that video file stay good with no corruption and with that i mean:
i can't scroll or navigate
[image]

here is my ffmpeg command: `-f image2 -framerate 10 -i C:\\Temp\\%06d.jpeg -c:v libx264 -r 10 -crf 37 -pix_fmt yuv420p C:Video\\" + s + ".mp4`

Comment: Define "Lots of time". I get a little feeling this is "wishfull thinking meets real world" - as in: decoding and reencoding 30.000 images takes a lot of time. I would start by not doing a screen capture but actually do encoding on the fly. And what is a 85 interval? 85 ms? That is really not needed - 5 images per second are more than enough to see what happened.

Comment: good point on the five images per second, now i am interesting in what you said about encoding on the fly, how to do that exactly?

Comment: By not storing jpb images. Take the bitmaps you get from the screen and feed them into the encoder. Generating and decoding jpbs is a LOT of work. No need to do it at all.

Comment: and what if electricity cut's off?

Comment: Then you have whatever has been written so far. Maybe you loose some images but seriously it is NOT IMPORTANT. How much you think happened in the last second before a power failure? Choose your battles wisely - if you need to flush disc buffers for every frame then you kill IO performance, and the gain is a coupple of lost frames. Not smart.